# How to set up a custom "Open Recent" submenu in macOS

Tags: macos, nsmenu

There is something very strange going on with the "Open Recent" menu that gets created with new "document" projects.

Even though, in Interface Builder, it appears like any other menu, it has some hidden special behavior, it appears.

I had tried to create my own list of items inside that menu, by setting its delegate to my AppDelegate, and then implement the `menuWillOpen` handler there. However, it never gets called. Doing the same with a newly added submenu, even though it looks the same in IB, it does work.

This is not actually a question any more. I had originally written this as a question, not understanding why I could not update this menu, but now it appears I just need to delete the default and add my own instead of modifying the auto-created one.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else runs into this weird issue, here's how to make it work:

1. Create a new "Open Recent" submenu just like the one that was added by default, and then delete the original one. Another way might be to edit the storyboard file directly and remove the `systemMenu` attribute from the default menu as in: `<menu key="submenu" title="Open Recent" systemMenu="recentDocuments" id="...">`
2. If you run the app now, you'll see two menus, because `NSDocumentController` creates one again automatically. To prevent that, create a custom subclass of `NSDocumentController` and implement this code in it:

```objc
- (NSUInteger)maximumRecentDocumentCount    {
    return 0;
}
```

3. To register your custom controller, invoke its `[CustomDocumentController sharedDocumentController];` once in your AppDelegate's `init` method.
4. Assign the delegate of your newly created submenu to the AppDelegate and implement this method in the AppDelegate:

```objc
- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    // Add your menu items here
}
```